# How to find a parametrization of a equation and to draw its picture.

Tags: computational-geometry, mathematica

I was wondering how to find a parametrization of $(x-t)^2+(y-t^2)^2-t^2=0$, and how to use a software like Mathematica to draw a picture of this equation based on the parametrization.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a mathematica forum on SE. Maybe this question can be migrated there instead.

Comment: While this is not strictly speaking off-topic here in Math.SE, for future reference, the website Arjang pointed you to is http://mathematica.stackexchange.com and is likely much better for such questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ContourPlot3D`. Here is an example parametrization:

```
ContourPlot3D[(x - t)^2 + (y - t^2)^2 == t^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {t, -1, 1}]
```

[image: Result of running ContourPlot3D]